# Python script to check whether a non-English character is Chinese or Japanese

Tags: python

I have python code that calls Windows software (collada refinery) through command line. It works fine in the UK but does not work on a machine in China/Taiwan. When the filename/filepath contains any Chinese characters this refinery fails to find or open file.

Python code:

```
# somewhere in the code
subprocess.popen("refinery -i <inputfile.dae> -o <outfile.dae> -x polylists2triangles", shell=True).wait())
```

When this inputfile.dae (I have to give just the name and then refinery adds current directory absolute path to it and makes full absolute path of this input file name> weird but that's not the question) is read by refinery it throws error or not able to open the file.

I want to add checking in python so that if input file name/path contains Chinese or non-English characters then, it throws user defined exception.

Comment: Don't use `shell=True` unless the command must be interpreted by a shell which most of the time isn't true.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718196/find-all-chinese-text-in-a-string-using-python-and-regex). The answers give regexes to remove CJK characters, but of course it can also be used to detect them.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define the file encoding after the first interpreter line

```
# _*_ coding=utf-8 _*_
```

and save the file as utf-8 also