# Python: Check if a string contains chinese character?

Tags: python, regex, unicode, python-2.x

A string maybe this

```
ipath= "./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt"
```

or this

```
ipath = './data/NCDC/ciampino/6240476818161dat.txt'
```

How do I know the first string contains **chinese**?

I find this answer maybe helpful: 
[Find all Chinese text in a string using Python and Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718196/find-all-chinese-text-in-a-string-using-python-and-regex)

but it didn't work out:

```
import re
ipath= "./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt"
re.findall(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', ipath) # => []
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2? In Python 3, it [seems working](https://ideone.com/lPHSky)  without `r` when declaring the regex.

Comment: `ipath= u"./data/NCD`, missed `u` before string.

Comment: Have a look at this [Python 2 demo](https://ideone.com/i0unNw) - does it work for you?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The matched string should be unicode as well

```
>>> import re
>>> ipath= u"./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt"
>>> re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', ipath)
[u'\u4e0a\u6d77', u'\u8679\u6865']
```

Comment: Some reason, add `u` gives me a syntax error, remove it works for me `re.findall(r"[\u4e00-\u9fff]+", ipath)`

Comment: @xecgr I get the same problem (and solution) mentioned by @LYu above. Please can you explain what the `u` is required for and why this is causing problems that can be resolved by removing it from your code?

Comment: Sorry, what does the reason? How do you get u4e00?

Answer (score 13):

If you just want to know whether there is a chinese character in your string you don't need `re.findall`, use `re.search` and the fact that match objects are truthy.

```
>>> import re
>>> ipath= u'./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt'
>>> ipath2 = u'./data/NCDC/ciampino/6240476818161dat.txt'
>>> for x in (ipath, ipath2):
...     if re.search(u'[\u4e00-\u9fff]', x):
...         print 'found chinese character in ' + x
... 
found chinese character in ./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt
```

Comment: should this be faster?

Answer (score 10):

Use `\p{Han}` regex with [`PyPi regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```py
import regex
ipath = "./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt"
print(regex.findall(r'\p{Han}+', ipath) )
# => ['上海', '虹桥']
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PzO3IL@oRKEoNT21giuzILEkw1ZBSU8/JbEkUd/P2cVZ/8mOrmdbt@u/mLnz2cKl@pbmBqZmRmZmZobmpgZARXolFSVKXAVFmXklGmAz9NIy81ISc3I0itRjCqo9EvNqtdV1FMAGaypoKigr2NopRKtDDAVKqEPMVY/9/x8A).

The `regex.search` is enough to detect:

```py
if regex.search(r'\p{Han}', ipath):
    print(f'"{ipath}" contains Chinese!')
```

Comment: Came here to add the same answer. The `regex` module is often needed anyway, and this way you don't need to keep double-checking that you've got the write character ranges in your code. Plus if a new block of Han characters are added in the future, you're likely to get your code updated via a dependency update automatically.

Answer (score 6):

And for those of us who don't care for `re`:

```
>>> ipath= u"./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/6240476818161dat.txt"
>>> for i in range(len(ipath)):
...  if ipath[i] > u'\u4e00' and ipath[i] < u'\u9fff':
...   print ipath[i]
... 
上
海
虹
桥
```

Edit: for the full list of Chinese characters this SO link is worth looking at as the range U+4E00..U+9FFF is not complete.
[What's the complete range for Chinese characters in Unicode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode)

Comment: This is simply taking what was done at the C level and moving it to Python.  For large blocks of text, it will be significantly slower.

Comment: @BradSolomon and your point is? This was a non `re` response, it doesn't claim to be anything else, certainly not faster.

Answer (score 4):

Using [these codepoint ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11415841/5719760), we can write an `is_cjk` function:

```
# list of cjk codepoint ranges
# tuples indicate the bottom and top of the range, inclusive
cjk_ranges = [
        ( 0x4E00,  0x62FF),
        ( 0x6300,  0x77FF),
        ( 0x7800,  0x8CFF),
        ( 0x8D00,  0x9FCC),
        ( 0x3400,  0x4DB5),
        (0x20000, 0x215FF),
        (0x21600, 0x230FF),
        (0x23100, 0x245FF),
        (0x24600, 0x260FF),
        (0x26100, 0x275FF),
        (0x27600, 0x290FF),
        (0x29100, 0x2A6DF),
        (0x2A700, 0x2B734),
        (0x2B740, 0x2B81D),
        (0x2B820, 0x2CEAF),
        (0x2CEB0, 0x2EBEF),
        (0x2F800, 0x2FA1F)
    ]

def is_cjk(char):
    char = ord(char)
    for bottom, top in cjk_ranges:
        if char >= bottom and char <= top:
            return True
    return False
```

Which we can then use to process text, using functions like `filter`, `any`, `all`, and `map` to process the text character-by-character, or compose more complex functions:

```
txt = "./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt"
txt_sanitized = "./data/NCDC/9705626661750dat.txt"
any(map(is_cjk, txt)) # True
any(map(is_cjk, txt_sanitized)) # False
''.join(filter(is_cjk, txt)) # '上海虹桥'
```

Note that the CJK ranges will include not only Chinese characters but also may include Korean and Japanese characters. For more complex usage, try a dedicated library like [`cjklib`](http://cjklib.org/0.3/).

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
ipath= raw_input()
print re.findall(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', ipath.decode("utf-8"))
```

Output:`./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt
[u'\u4e0a\u6d77', u'\u8679\u6865']`

You need to decode the input to make it unicode.

or

```
 import re
 ipath= unicode(raw_input(),encoding="utf-8")
 print re.findall(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', ipath)
```

Answer (score 1):

`''` is a bytestring on Python 2. Either add `from __future__ import unicode_literals` at the top of the module or use unicode literals: `u''`:

```
>>> import re
>>> ipath= u"./data/NCDC/上海/虹桥/9705626661750dat.txt"
>>> re.findall(ur'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', ipath)
[u'\u4e0a\u6d77', u'\u8679\u6865']
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366068/whats-the-complete-range-for-chinese-characters-in-unicode), the range should be `[\u2E80-\u2FD5\u3190-\u319f\u3400-\u4DBF\u4E00-\u9FCC]`