# How to filter first occurrence of Mandarin characters from a column in pandas and put that in another column

Tags: python, pandas, chinese-locale

I have a dataframe `df` :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [1,2,3,4,5],
           "eng_mand" :["後山 4.7·3 reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場",
                        "Taipei City 台北市Taiwan",
                        "綠山谷海芋園餐廳 3.8·52 reviews",
                        "名陽匍休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園",
                        "Menghuanhu"]})
```

it looks like:

```
   ID                                   eng_mand
0   1  後山 4.7·3 reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場
1   2                      Taipei City 台北市Taiwan
2   3                    綠山谷海芋園餐廳 3.8·52 reviews
3   4                        名陽匍休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園
4   5                                 Menghuanhu
```

I want to filter the first occurrence of the mandarin characters from the column `eng_mand` and want to put that in another column `mandarin_char`.My final output must look like:

```
   ID                                   eng_mand             mandarin_char          
0   1  後山 4.7·3 reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場        後山
1   2                      Taipei City 台北市Taiwan             台北市
2   3                    綠山谷海芋園餐廳 3.8·52 reviews         綠山谷海芋園餐廳
3   4                        名陽匍休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園       名陽匍休閒農莊
4   5                                 Menghuanhu
```

How can I do this in python - pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) all [chinese chars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2718203/2901002) and add `fillna` for replace `NaN`s to empty strings if necessary:

```
df['mandarin_char'] = df['eng_mand'].str.extract(r'([\u4e00-\u9fff]+)').fillna('')
print (df)
   ID                                   eng_mand mandarin_char
0   1  後山 4.7·3 reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場            後山
1   2                      Taipei City 台北市Taiwan           台北市
2   3                    綠山谷海芋園餐廳 3.8·52 reviews      綠山谷海芋園餐廳
3   4                        名陽匍休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園       名陽匍休閒農莊
4   5                                 Menghuanhu
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`str.findall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.findall.html#pandas.Series.str.findall) and pass the regex for the [mandarin range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34587346/python-check-if-a-string-contains-chinese-character) :

```
In[14]:
df['mandarin_char'] = df['eng_mand'].str.findall('[\u4e00-\u9fff]+').str[0]
df

Out[14]: 
   ID                                   eng_mand mandarin_char
0   1  後山 4.7·3 reviews Community Center 竹杉園休閒農場            後山
1   2                      Taipei City 台北市Taiwan           台北市
2   3                    綠山谷海芋園餐廳 3.8·52 reviews      綠山谷海芋園餐廳
3   4                        名陽匍休閒農莊minyangpu大賞園       名陽匍休閒農莊
4   5                                 Menghuanhu           NaN
```

You can call `fillna('')` on the result to replace `NaN` if required.