# Remove chinese characters

Tags: python, unicode-string

I'm want to remove the chinese characters of a text or any other any character that isnt Latin

i tried using encoding='UTF-8' but dont works

Text Example: 
Um olhar maligno que só desejava a destruição!
“Parem-o!”
Ele ordenou os demônios.
Os demônios abriram suas asas, seguraram suas armas e lançaram magia.
Σ? ?Γαπ? ……. ”
Γει? !!

I want that return
Um olhar maligno que só desejava a destruição!
“Parem-o!”
Ele ordenou os demônios.
Os demônios abriram suas asas, seguraram suas armas e lançaram magia.
? ?? ……. ”
? !!

Comment: here is a way to find them all: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718196/find-all-chinese-text-in-a-string-using-python-and-regex and then you only have to delete. hope it helps

Comment: BTW I think this is Greek, not Chinese.

Answer (score 4):

Try this, is this what you wanted?

```
test = "Um olhar maligno que só desejava a destruição! “Parem-o!” Ele ordenou os demônios. Os demônios abriram suas asas, seguraram suas armas e lançaram magia. Σ? ?Γαπ? ……. ” Γει? !!"
import re
regex = re.compile('[^\u0020-\u024F]')
#First parameter is the replacement, second parameter is your input string
regex.sub('', test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this extension of Latin encoding:

ISO 8859-2 (Latin 2)

Comment: I'm curious. Why did you suggest ISO 8859-2 (Latin 2) rather than ISO/IEC 8859-1 (Latin 1)?

Comment: Latin-2 includes characters of Eastern European languages